# Get the last post ID

Tags: plugins, posts, database

I'm trying to understand the ID mechanism in `wp_posts` in WordPress.

Whenever I add a product (woocommerce), page, or an image, they are recorded in `wp_posts` and assigned an incremented id. Let's say, I added 100 items. The id of the last item would be 100. Then I removed 50 of them. The next item I add will have the id 101, not 51. So this id mechanism doesn't check the existing items for the next generated id. Last used id must be stored internally. How/where can I find it?

---

This is a follow up to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194493/get-the-last-product-id) os SO.

Comment: The ID column is just set to auto increment in MYSQL. The database handles it.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html Nothing to do with WordPress or WooCommerce.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I feel so silly right now. I should've guessed. First thing I thought was that it was controlled by WordPress :)