# How to get a custom post with the largest ID (not the last post by date)

Tags: get-posts

I would like to get the (one) post with the last ID, even if it is not the last post by date. The post belongs to a custom post type.

I need this to assign custom id numbers to my orders. When creating a new order, I am going to find the post with the largest ID, get its order number from its meta, increment it and assign it to the new one. I DO UPDATE order post when order gets changed in any way and update its date to make it appear at the top of the post list. Therefore, the last post by date that WP gets does not necessarily have the largest ID number. I would like to get the post with the largest post ID.

This is an example list of my post ids

3460
3465
3464
3463
3462
3461
3459

I need to get 3465

This is my code:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'my_order_cpt',
   'post_status' => array('confirmed', 'paid', ..... , 'closed'),
   'numberposts' => 1,
   'orderby' => 'ID',
   'order'   => 'DESC'
);
$numbers = get_posts($args);
```

However, this gives me the last post by date. In my exaple, it's 3460.

All the answers I found, e.g. [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325638/get-the-last-post-id), describe getting the last post by date.

I know there's a way to do this with a wpdb query ("SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key='[plugin_prefix]_order_number' ORDER BY CAST(meta_value AS UNSIGNED) DESC LIMIT 1" + checking if post is  not a draft and not in trash) or by getting all posts of the post type and playing with the array, but is there a way with get_posts()? Maybe, with meta_query? The order number is a separate meta field named '[plugin_prefix]_order_number'.

Comment: Looks like this should work. There's no 'numberposts' parameter, so perhaps that's confusing things. Try 'posts_per_page' => 1

Comment: Also, it shouldn't, but I wonder if `'orderby'  => array( 'ID' => 'DESC' )` and remove `order` parameter makes any difference?

Comment: @mozboz Numberposts is an alias of post_per_page, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Comment: Ah, nice. I didn't know that - usually refer to the WP_Query page for args

Comment: I checked, " 'orderby'  => array( 'ID' => 'DESC' ) and remove order parameter" does not change the result

Comment: Normally the latest post has the *largest* ID. If that isn't the case for you, you might have a problem with your setup. Anyway, try retrieving only the post IDs using `fields` parameter in your query. Then sort that array and get the first index.

Comment: Your code looks correct. I suspect the problem might be with your larger concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I was kind of wrong when I tried to get the largest ID. What I needed was to get posts by, and then to sort by, the order number itself! Here's what I came up with:

```
$num_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_store_order',
    'post_status' => array('mystatus_1', 'mystatus_2', 'mystatus_N'),
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'my_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'my_order_number',
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'EXIST'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'my_clause',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

Also, since post meta is a string, I added 'type' => 'numeric' so when being sorted it would be treated as a number (1,2,10 vs 1,10,2)

[This post](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html) helped me a lot